# how to add a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, redirect

I want to add a 301 redirect plugin to a Craft CMS 2.6 website. I only have user permission as well.

Please give me steps on how to add my redirects to the back-end of the site?

Comment: Do you have access to the control panel and to `/admin/settings/plugins` otherwise you won't be able to do that without enough knowledge. I would suggest you to contact your developer

Answer (score 1):

You need access to the server your Craft site is installed on to install the plugin code in the `craft/plugins` folder.

In addition to that, you will need administrator access to the Craft Control Panel to access Settings->Plugins in order to install any plugins.

Most likely, you'll need to contact the administrator of your site or whomever developed/still maintains it to progress.